# Using template for creating view for select stored procedure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a controller for select stored procedure. Now I am trying to add view for this controller using template.

Controller code block

```
public ActionResult Display()
{            
    return View(db.P_GET_USER().ToList());
}
```

This is the code block of `context` class for the stored procedure:

```
public virtual ObjectResult<P_GET_USER_Result> P_GET_USER()
{
    return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<P_GET_USER_Result>("P_GET_USER");
}
```

Code block of `P_GET_USER_Result.cs` complex type:

```
public partial class P_GET_USER_Result
{
        public string USERNAME { get; set; }
        public string NAME { get; set; }
        public int ROLE { get; set; }
        public int STATUS { get; set; }
        public string CREATED_DATE { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to create view keeping template as list and modal class as `P_GET_USER_Result` (`final.Models`), I get a pop up error

> Unable to retrieve meta data for P_GET_USER_Result. One or more validation errors were detected during model generation

Please see the attached screenshot for the detailed error message.

When I searched the internet for tutorials, I found most of them show are creating empty template and then adding content in view. So can't I use list template. Please help.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Following your error, your Entity must have a key. You should change your Models:

```
public partial class P_GET_USER_Result
{
    [key]
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string USERNAME { get; set; }
    public string NAME { get; set; }
    public int ROLE { get; set; }
    public int STATUS { get; set; }
    public string CREATED_DATE { get; set; }
}
```

You can choose any fields set to key, but it's must identify.

Comment: If you see the error image, it is showing no key for every entity in the model. Why is it so? When I add key property to the above class still getting the same error.

Comment: I added `[key]` for each of the table entity in the model. Now I got the result. But please can you explain me why is it so? What is the logic behind this. Thank You!!!

Comment: You can refer article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/entity-type . An entity similar table in a database, you need to define at least one key for a relationship.